# VS2005 VB.NET XML Comments ''' - stopped working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, comments

I'm using VS2005 in a solution with a mix of VB and C# in different projects.

I use this solution on several different computers and XML comments with both /// (c#) and ''' (VB) have been fine for months.

all of a sudden, on my main development machine, they've stopped working in VB. They still work in C#.

They work in other projects, too (in VB). It's just all VB projects within this one solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I can't pinpoint when it stopped working as I haven't modified much of the VB code for weeks/months.

Answer (score 28):

aha!

in the 'compile' tab under properties, the 'generate documentation' checkbox was not ticked.

looking at SVN it looks like someone checked in the VB projects with this unticked, for some reason.

thanks for the help! it's my first time using this site. looks like the guys involved have done a good job. i love the fact you don't have to register.

Comment: This has been driving me up a wall for months!! Thanks for solving this.

Comment: great, this came up as a suggestion when I was about to post this question myself!

Comment: I have just been muddling around with this VS2008 for the better part of the last hour trying to solve that one thing. Thank you for your prompt (and funny) answer!

Answer (score 3):

The one reason this might be the case is that the XML file is no longer being created/updated. Make sure the XML Documentation file is set in the project property pages. Has your XML file been put under source control and if so is it checked out on a build. If not then it won't update.