# VB.NET code snippet to insert comment block in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have used `///` snippet in C# when I use Visual Studio 2010 and this will create a pre-defined comment block.

When I use VB.NET the same princioal using `'''` doesn't work. I can make my own snippets to intellisense, but is there predefined snippet for this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108717/vs2005-vb-net-xml-comments-stopped-working) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269307/autogenerating-xml-comments-in-vb-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Project Explorer select your Project and than open the **Project Properties**.
Goto **Compile** and be sure that **"Generate XML documentation file"** is checked.
Without that option the ''' snipped is disabled in vb .net